# How add a folder with files inside AOSP root dir?

Tags: linux, android-source, ramdisk, fstab

I'm trying to add a folder inside AOSP root directory using BOARD_ROOT_EXTRA_FOLDERS in Android.mk file, but when I flash it the folder or file isn't there. Also tried to use PRODUCT_COPY_FILES to insert folder (e.g. PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += device/qcom/msm8953_64/my_folder:/) But no success. Is there a way to add files and folders to root dir? Any tip will be very welcome

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found [this](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:device/generic/qemu/qemu_base.mk?q=:root%2F&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject)
in AOSP source, and it seems like that is how to add files to the root directory.

Please try : `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += device/qcom/msm8953_64/my_folder/file1:root/my_folder/file1`

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36695458/2443657)
in StackOverflow on how to copy files from a directory.
Because you need to add your directory with its files to the root directory, you can try this : `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += $(call find-copy-subdir-files,*,device/qcom/msm8953_64/my_folder,root/my_folder)`